# Using databases on Android development

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

I have just started on Android development, and I'm having lots of doubts on the implementation of Databases in apps. I need to use a database that will already be filled with information and another database that will be updated upon information provided by the application. Through my searches I wasn't avble to find a tutorial that would help me to implement a database that is filled with information, and that is the first of my doubts. The second one is the following: how do I access information based on the row they are in, and is there any way to implement bubble sorting in a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personnaly would go to MySQL
Here is a start
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm\

Also to create, modify... your database(s) on a computer I use MySQL Lite
https://www.sqlite.org/

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks! Though for my app online database wouldn't be a good idea.

Comment: Android got built in SQL no need to to have it online ! check this http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: Thanks! I thought that because the tutorial you recommended requires an online database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not big on databases myself, but a new upcoming technology (that a lot of top tutorial sites such as TeamTreehouse teach how to use) is called https://parse.com/products/core . It is a really simple to implement backend.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, but as this is my first app, I was looking for a free alternative

Comment: It is free to a certain use. Trust me it's perfect